# vuejs3 good behavior with unMounted, bad with watch

Tags: vuejs3

I'm getting crazy with VueJS3.

I created a service like this which is getting data from an API

```
import axios from "axios";
import {  reactive} from "vue";

export default function () {


    let products = reactive([]);
    async function searchProduct(param) {
        console.log(`dans la fonction avec param ${param}`)
        const url = "http://localhost:5000/product/?search="+param;
        const result = await axios.get(url);
        products=products.splice(0,0,...result.data)
        console.log(products)
        return products
    }
    
    return { products, searchProduct };
}
```

So far so good. When the page load (call made with hook onMounted, everything is fine)
Now I have an input html elem linked to the ref searchQuery.
When I change the value in my input element, I can see from the logs of the api that the hook watch is doing the call, but my reactive value "products" is never updated.

```
<script>
import {  ref,watch,onMounted } from "vue";
import serviceFactory from "./dataservice";

export default {
    setup() {
      let searchQuery = ref("");

      // Create them by calling the exported function
      let {  products,searchProduct } = serviceFactory();
        
      // This works when page load 
      onMounted(async () => await searchProduct(searchQuery.value ));

      // This DOESN't works when the ref searchQuery is updated (through input HTML) : I see the api call but products is not updated :(
      watch(searchQuery, (searchQuery) => {
          await searchProduct(searchQuery )
        })

      return {
        searchProduct,       // from factory function
        products,       // from factory function,
        searchQuery
      };
    },
};
</script>
```

I don't understand the reason of my failure, any advice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting your products array in the response thus losing reactivity. One reason why I recommend using `const` instead of `let` in most cases.

You can either use a reactive object or just a `ref` for your products and assigning the results to its `value`:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { ref } from "vue";

export default function () {

    const products = ref([]);
    async function searchProduct(param) {
        console.log(`dans la fonction avec param ${param}`)
        const url = "http://localhost:5000/product/?search="+param;
        const result = await axios.get(url);
        products.value = products.value.splice(0,0,...result.data)
        console.log(products.value)
        return products.value
    }
    
    return { products, searchProduct };
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's now perfectly working, I didn't understood that I was breaking the reactivity chain by overriding my array.